# Monitor progress and intermediate results in Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, listener

I have a simple Spark task, something like this:

```
JavaRDD<Solution> solutions = rdd.map(new Solve());
// Select best solution by some criteria
```

The solve routine takes some time. For a demo application, I need to get some property of each solution **as soon as it is calculated**, before the call to `rdd.map` terminates.

I've tried using accumulators and `SparkListener`, overriding the `onTaskEnd` method, but it seems to be called only at the end of the mapping, not per thread, E.g.

```
sparkContext.sc().addSparkListener(new SparkListener() {
  public void onTaskEnd(SparkListenerTaskEnd taskEnd) {
    // do something with taskEnd.taskInfo().accumulables()
  }
});
```

How can I get an asynchronous message for each map function end?

Spark runs locally or in a standalone cluster mode.

Answers can be in Java or Scala, both are OK.

Comment: Have you considered using [Spark Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/streaming/) and streaming the input data to the app? In Spark Streaming you can divide the input data into smaller batches and process every one of them independently. Seems to fit your use case.

Comment: @jannis for other reasons, streaming is not a preferred solution

Comment: How many tasks are you running? If you have #tasks < #CPUs, you'll indeed get a bunch of calls to `onTaskEnd` only near the end of the run, because each task would just use an entire core throughout the execution. Alternatively, if you create much more tasks than available CPUs, you'll force Spark to split the data into smaller pieces which will be processed gradually - maybe that way you'll get intermediate calls to `onTaskEnd` with meaningful data.

Comment: One more question: how does `Solve` look like? What operations does it include? Does it include operations on other RDDs than the single one mentioned?

Comment: @jannis `Solve()` is a single-threaded non-Spark loop-driven search algorithm. It terminates within 2-4 minutes

Comment: Please provide execution DAG and the timeline visualization for your job (from the Spark UI - as described [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/22/understanding-your-spark-application-through-visualization.html)).

Comment: I suspect @TzachZohar is right. The number of elements in `rdd` is too small, so it may look like `onTaskEnd` is not called enough times. I'm checking it now.

Comment: It seems that Spark does not monitor the per-element progress in each task, so I need to re-engineer my workflow to get the resolution I want. Thank you for your comments.